# Equivalent to cvSetImageROI in the OpenCV C++ interface

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm migrating an old test application from the OpenCV C interface to the new C++ interface (I wish to learn it). What's the equivalent, using the C++ interface, of `cvSetImageROI` and `cvResetImageROI`? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually, it's right on the [docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html). Shame on me.

```
//Make a rectangle
Rect roi(10, 20, 100, 50);
//Point a cv::Mat header at it (no allocation is done)
Mat image_roi = image(roi)
```

Comment: To answer a question on made on my answer (now deleted), let's say you have a valid `cv::Mat` named `my_mat`. To convert it to an `IplImage*` all you need to do is a cast operation: `IplImage* img = &(IplImage)my_mat;`

Comment: @karlphillip Using `IplImage* img = &(IplImage)my_mat;` raises me the following warning: `warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue`. Is this normal? (VS2005)

Comment: It's best to do `IplImage img = (IplImage)my_mat;` and then pass `&img` whenever you need to use a memory pointer to it.

Comment: The link to *docs* does not work. Can you please post the actual documentation instead of a blog link?

Comment: @Nawaz That was the link to OpenCV documentation six and half years ago when that question was answered. I haven't touched OpenCV in a long time and I can't point you to the current docs, unfortunately.

Comment: @VitorPy: I've found it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, there is also an overloaded version of the [cv::Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa7ec97373406215f2d4bc72cc1d27036) constructor that takes an ROI (cv::Rect) as a parameter.

```
cv::Mat img = ...;
cv::Rect roi(x,y,width,height);
cv::Mat img_crop(img, roi);
```