# Stitching 2 images in opencv

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to stitch 2 images just for start for panography. I"ve already found keypoints, found homography using RANSAC but I can't figure out how to align these 2 images (i'm new at opencv). Now part of code

```
vector<Point2f> points1, points2;
for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
{
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    points1.push_back( keypoints1[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    points2.push_back( keypoints2[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}

/* Find Homography */
Mat H = findHomography( Mat(points2), Mat(points1), CV_RANSAC );

/* warp the image */
warpPerspective(mImg2, warpImage2, H, Size(mImg2.cols*2, mImg2.rows*2), INTER_CUBIC);
```

and I need to stitch `Mat mImg1` where is loaded the first image and `Mat warpImage2` where is the warped second image. Can you pls show me how to do that? I also have the warped image cut up and I know I have to change the homography matrix but for now I need to align these two images. Thank you for helping.

Edit: With Martin Beckett's help I added this code

```
//Point a cv::Mat header at it (no allocation is done)
Mat final(Size(mImg2.cols*2 + mImg1.cols, mImg2.rows*2),CV_8UC3);

//velikost img1
Mat roi1(final, Rect(0, 0,  mImg1.cols, mImg1.rows));
Mat roi2(final, Rect(0, 0, warpImage2.cols, warpImage2.rows));
warpImage2.copyTo(roi2);
mImg1.copyTo(roi1);
imshow("final", final);
```

and it's working now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create a new larger image of the correct combined size, then [make ROIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041181/equivalent-to-cvsetimageroi-in-the-opencv-c-interface) of the size of the existing images in the positions you want them in the final image and copy the existing images to the ROIs.

Comment: I did your steps, as edited by Bodyboard, But I get always the final image as a gray image totally. ! while I'm sure that my resulted image is warped correctly. Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: @dervish are your source images 3channel? If not you have to convert them before stitching, or make the result the same type as the source and then convert