# Having some difficulty in doing Multicamera Image stitching and camera calibration

Tags: image-processing, opencv, camera-calibration

I've asked a lot of image-stitching-related questions here due to the fact that I'm SOO dumb to understand certain things :(

I'm currently working on a homography-based multicamera image stitching and having some problems that I can't solve by myself. **I use Visual Studio 2008/2010 and OpenCV 2.3.1 to work on my project.**

I'm gonna describe them below:

**First of all, I've put some stuff(code, video...etc) that'll be mentioned later in the following link as I'm limited to post 2 links at most currently...**

https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B2r9FmkcbNwAM2drVHVJUktnS3M/edit

Plz take a look at the video "Stitching_HomographyBased.avi", which exists in the link mentioned above.

The 12-second video shows how my code is currently working. I use 2 webcams, put them as close as possible and in different orientations with rougly 30%~50% overlapping region. 
Image 1 and Image 2 show the images taken by the 2 cameras separately.
The wider window, of course, shows the aligned(stitched) panorama.

However, the video shows a problem that **the warped image is not correctly aligned(see 0:04, where my lab mate stands at the border of the 2 images)**

After having some survey on related studies, I guessed that one of the main reasons that lead to this result may be due to the fact that I didn't do camera calibration on both cameras and the radial and tangential distortions cause the error. **Is what I guess correct or there may be some other factors that also make this mismatch happen?**

I then tried to do camera calibration with an existing code for camera calibration and a chessboard, but I just kept getting weird results. Plz see another video named "BadCalibration.avi" in the link.
**What's wrong with the way I calibrate the camera?**

My code is also uploaded in the link above and it's named Stitching1024.cpp

Thanks for all the helps.

Comment: I'd recommend that you edit this question. SO questions should be specific, "I tried to do camera calibration...but I just kept getting wierd results" doesn't really reveal anything about what is right/wrong about your approach. Also, if a section of your code is relevant then put it directly into the question...

Comment: Stitching images together can only be done correctly if all the elements in the image are approximately the same distance from the cameras. Otherwise [parallax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) will prevent everything from lining up properly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll edit this post sooner or later...