# smoothing in a particular area of image

Tags: objective-c, ios, image-processing, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set ROI in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206466/how-to-set-roi-in-opencv)

I'm trying to use a smoothing/blur filter on an image but only in a particular path /area of the source. (Using openCV currently)

How can that be done?

right now I'm doing something like

```
cv::GaussianBlur(im, newim, cv::Size(5,5),1.5);
```

But I would like to be doing

```
cv::GaussianBlur(im, newim, cv::Size(5,5),1.5,MyClosedPath);
```

I can also use any of the ios classes if it is easier to do. (Haven't found a way for that yet either)

Comment: Set a ROI (Region of Interest), then copy it to another Mat, Smooth it, and copy it back to the original Mat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a submatrix out of your original matrix eg:

```
cv::Mat subMat = originalMatrix(cv::Rect(x, y, width, height));
```

where x,y, width, height are the position of your subimage.
Then perform your gaussian blur on the submatrix.

[edit]
If you want to blur complex shapes, one way would be to blur the full image, and then use mat.copyTo with the mask of your blurred parts:

```
cv::Mat mask = ?; // this should be a CV_8U image with 0 pixels everywhere but where you want to blur the original image
cv::Mat blurred;
cv::gaussianBlur(image, blurred, cv::Size(5,5),1.5);
cv::Mat output = image.clone();
blurred.copyTo(output, mask);
```

Comment: I need to do some more complex shapes (and with "holes") - also how would i combine them back to one image?

Comment: any change made in the submatrix are also applied to your original matrix. I will edit my answer for your second question

Comment: Let me know if that answered your question by marking it! thx