# Copy an cv::Mat inside a ROI of another one

Tags: c++, opencv, copy, roi

I need to copy a `cv::Mat` image (source) to an ROI of another (Destination) `cv::Mat` image.

I found [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041181/equivalent-to-cvsetimageroi-in-the-opencv-c-interface), but it seems that it does not work for my case.
Do you have any pointers how could I do this using the OpenCV C++ interface?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

OpenCV 2.4:

```
src.copyTo(dst(Rect(left, top, src.cols, src.rows)));
```

OpenCV 2.x:

```
Mat dst_roi = dst(Rect(left, top, src.cols, src.rows));
src.copyTo(dst_roi);
```

Comment: thanks! I did it like this and works great: bboxImage.copyTo(destImage.colRange(startCol,startCol+bboxImage.cols).rowRange(startRow,startRow+bboxImage.rows));

Comment: Yields `no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat)’
viewtest2.cpp:172:61: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1651:10: note: void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::OutputArray) const` in OpenCV 2.4.6. Second solution does work however, but it results into an image with just src.

Comment: what is the difference between previous version of opencv? why the code differs?

Comment: `src.copyTo(dst(Rect(left, top, src.cols, src.rows));`
3x '(' and 2x ')'?
`Mat dst_roi = dst(Rect(left, top, src.cols, src.rows);` 
2x '(' and 1x ')'?
Untested code?

Comment: Is this dst_roi,  a pointer to the certain part of the destination image? I guess it should be so..

Comment: valgrind reports memory leaks when I do this with OpenCV 3.2. But it works ^^

Comment: @lawilog Did you ever figure out how to do this without leaking memory? I'm running into the same issue, and am surprised that there is such a big bug in commonly used OpenCV stuff...

Answer (score 13):

In addition or correction to above answers, if you want to copy a smaller region of open `Mat` to another `Mat`, you should do:

```
src(Rect(left,top,width, height)).copyTo(dst);
```

Answer (score 11):

Did work for me this way:

```
Mat imgPanel(100, 250, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
Mat imgPanelRoi(imgPanel, Rect(0, 0, imgSrc.cols, imgSrc.rows));
imgSrc.copyTo(imgPanelRoi);

imshow("imgPanel", imgPanel);
waitKey();
```

I am using Opencv 2.4.9
Based on Andrey's answer.