# Concatenate Mat in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, concatenation, opencv-mat

I have a couple of images in `Mat` objects all with same dimensions
I'd like to create one bix `cv::Mat` object to hold them all

So the dimension of the new matrix is: *widthNew = widthOld x number of matrices*, height remains unchanged.

I found that such a copy could be done using:

```
void cvCopy(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, const CvArr* mask=NULL)
```

but then, how could the mask be defined three different times for the three matrices?.

Regards,
Moataz

Comment: Be careful that the max size for an IplImage is somewhere around 4000*4000. You might also have to reduce resolution of your input image

Comment: Mask is optional, you do not need to define one.

Comment: alright. I'll put that in mind, thnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use an roi to define an image which is actually a region of the destination image and then copy to that. see [Copy an cv::Mat inside a ROI of another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481411/opencv-copy-an-cvmat-inside-a-roi-of-another)

Answer (score 15):

I think there is an easy way to do this. *OpenCV* has a not documented methods called `hconcat()` and `vconcat()`. The first one is for horizontal concatenation and the second one for vertical concatenation.

You can use them in this way:

```
Mat A, B;
... //In this part you initialize the Mat A and Mat B.

Mat H, V; //These are the destination matrices
hconcat(A, B, H);
vconcat(A, B, V);
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: The destination can be the same as one of the sources so `vconcat(out, out1, out); vconcat(out, out2, out);` worked well for me in a multithreaded context (for combining output from individual threads).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take look at [the source code of `cvShowManyImages()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/DisplayManyImages), which is a function that takes several images as input and concatenates them into a single 3-channel image to be displayed:

> The method used is to set the ROIs of a Single Big image and then resizing 
>   and copying the input images on to the Single Big Image.

If you create a destination image big enough to hold your other images, you won't need to resize them.

If you want to know how to convert between `IplImage` <-> `cv::Mat`, check [this thread](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/IplImage-lt-gt-cv-Mat-td5317470.html).

Comment: sounds interesting, thnx. I think I'll copy the idea to implement something similar using pure cv::Mat instead of IpImage