# how to add cropped image to center of another image in c++ code

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two images

one: is cropped image with dimension

another: is black image with different dimension

now i need to put the first image in center of the second image

any one can help me

thanks

Comment: Check for duplicates before posting questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481411/opencv-copy-an-cvmat-inside-a-roi-of-another

Answer (score 1):

Assuming black image is larger then cropped image and both images are same type and same channels:

```
cropped_image.copyTo(my_black_image(cv::Rect((my_black_image.cols - cropped_image.cols)/2, (my_black_image.rows - cropped_image.rows)/2, cropped_image.cols, cropped_image.rows)));
```

Comment: but when i use this copyTo function i have an opencv error:assertion failed <!fixed size<>::<<mat*>obj->size size<cols,rows> core\src\matrix line 1392

Comment: Is you black image larger than cropped image? Which version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: i have fixed size for black image and a different size for cropped image, i need to make these cropped images in center and all with the same size without using resize function

Comment: Please see little update, I have checked the code and it is working fine.