# OpenCV - Zero padding of Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, padding

Suppose I have a Mat variable small_image with dimensions 98x158x32 (type float). Now I want to zero pad this image (ie. add a border of zeros to the image). I want to add 7 zeros above and below the image, and 12 zeros left and right of the image. The first idea was to use the cv copyMakeBorder (see [copyMakeBorder doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder)), which seems perfect for this:

```
    int old_size[3];
    old_size[0] = 98;
    old_size[1] = 158;
    old_size[2] = 32;

    int pad_size[3];
    pad_size[0] = old_size[0] + 2 * 7;
    pad_size[1] = old_size[1] + 2 * 12;
    pad_size[2] = old_size[2];

    cv::Mat image_padded(3, pad_size, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0)); //Initialize the larger Mat to 0

    copyMakeBorder(small_image,image_padded,7,7,12,12,BORDER_CONSTANT,Scalar(0));
```

However, this code gives a memcopy error. Does anyone see the problem here?

The alternative as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481411/opencv-copy-an-cvmat-inside-a-roi-of-another) does not work either:

```
cv::Rect roi( cv::Point( 12, 7 ), small_image.size() );
small_image.copyTo( image_padded( roi ) );
```

It claims that "Assertion failed (m.dims <= 2)", while both Mat variables are 3D matrices.

Any help to achieve the zero padding would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: copyMakeBorder is most likely not working since it's designed for 2D matrices representing images (although can be multichannel). What you have here is a 3D Mat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the methods you described work since they are meant to be used for 2D matrices. You have a 3D Mat which requires that you specify ranges in all three dimensions. You can use the `()` operator which works with an array of ranges combined with `copyTo` as in the example below.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int old_size[3];
  old_size[0] = 5;
  old_size[1] = 5;
  old_size[2] = 2;

  int pad_size[3];
  pad_size[0] = old_size[0] + 2 * 1;
  pad_size[1] = old_size[1] + 2 * 2;
  pad_size[2] = old_size[2];

  cv::Mat small_image(3, old_size, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(1));
  cv::Mat image_padded(3, pad_size, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));

  cv::Range ranges[3];
  ranges[0] = cv::Range(1, old_size[0]+1);
  ranges[1] = cv::Range(2, old_size[1]+2);
  ranges[2] = cv::Range(0, old_size[2]);

  small_image.copyTo(image_padded(ranges));

  for (int i = 0; i < pad_size[0]; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < pad_size[1]; j++)
      for (int k = 0; k < pad_size[2]; k++)
        std::cout << image_padded.at<float>(i, j, k) << ", ";
}
```

which will give:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Good solution! I struggled however with the right initialization of `Mat image_padded`. If you loaded an image via `Mat A; A=imread(..)` you need (at least under Ubuntu) the parameters:
`cv::Mat image_padded(2, pad_size, CV_8UC3_U, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0))`
Hope this saves someone's time.

Answer (score 2):

We could also use a combination of `rowRange` and `colRange` methods to set our region of interest to a subsection of 3 dimensional padded image( all zeros ). That could easily followed by copying unpadded image onto it.

```
cv::Mat image_padded(3, pad_size, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0));
int xPad = 12;
int yPad = 7;
Mat area = image_padded.rowRange(xPad, xPad + 98).colRange(yPad, yPad + 158);
small_image.copyTo( area );
```

Comment: <sub>Curious about the purpose of this 3D image </sub>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This indeed seems the most intuitive method. It's not really an image, but rather a 3D matrix containing data. I just renamed the variables to a more general case for this post. Usually, I would perform such operations in Matlab but the project I'm working on limits me to C++