# Performing Filter in a specific part of the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

The defined method for filters example binary filter takes two parameters, the source image MAT and destination image MAT and performs filter on the full image.

But what if I want to perform operations like filter in only a part of the image for which we have the contour points (either Point or MatOfPoint).

The solution that I am looking for is in JAVA.

Code :: `Imgproc.bilateralFilter(src,dest,9,7,11);`

Comment: you can use ROIs to restrict filters to a certain subset of your image

Comment: @Piglet I did go through ROIs but how to use that as if you see the edit, the code takes the source image and `ROI` are areas themselves so how to use in the current api which takes the source image and dest image.

Comment: crop the image befor you put it into the filter?

Comment: @arqam set the ROI of your image `image[ROI]` as the source, and set the same ROI for your destination `destination[ROI]`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds this `image[ROI]` will be a cropped image right? As what I want finally is the full image, with just that part of the region filtered.
@Piglet

Comment: @arqam yes; what I said will do exactly what you want. See [this Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029697/how-can-i-do-image-processing-operations-only-in-roi-part-of-original-image-dire) for an example. Using a rectangle to get a region of interest does *not* create a new copy of an image, but just references part of that original image. So if you modify the values inside an ROI, it modifies it in the whole image.