# How to do image processing on a certain area of an image in python OpenCV 3?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

Considering I have the coordinates already of the area of the image I want to do image processing on. [It was already explained here using Rect but how do you do this on python OpenCV 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029697/how-can-i-do-image-processing-operations-only-in-roi-part-of-original-image-dire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you gave, it seems you don't want the output in a different image variable, given that you know the coordinates of the region you want to process. I'll assume your image processing function to be `cv2.blur()` so this is how it'll be:

```
image[y:y+height, w:w+width] = cv2.blur(image[y:y+height, w:w+width], (11,11))
```

Here, x & y are your ROI starting co-ordinates, and height & width are the height, width of the ROI

Hope this is what you wanted, or if it's anything different, provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very useful if you would provide more details and maybe some code you've tried.

From my understanding, you want to do image processing on a region of an image array only. You can do something like

```
foo(im[i1:i2, j1:j2, :])
```

Where `foo` is your image processing function.