# Crop Mat image in OpenCV 2.4.3 (iOS)

Tags: ios, opencv

I am trying to crop images coming out of the video stream with OpenCV for iOS.  I am not trying to do anything fancy, simply crop the image, and display it.  I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041181/equivalent-to-cvsetimageroi-in-the-opencv-c-interface), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267191/how-to-crop-a-cvmat-in-opencv), neither seem to work for me.  As a delegate method, I get the current cv::Mat image passed in, so all I need is the code that will create the crop effect.

I could do something as complicated as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098073/adjust-corners-and-crop-the-image-opencv) if need be, but I only need a rectangular crop, so I think there is an easier way.  I just dont understand why setting the ROI is not working for me!

```
cv::Rect myROI(10, 10, 100, 100);
cv::Mat croppedImage = src(myROI);

src.copyTo(croppedImage);


[displayView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCVMat:src]];
```

^^^not working, just displaying original image

Comment: Hi am facing the same problem. Can you please have a look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756505/croping-an-image-in-ios-uisng-opencv-face-detect

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem in your code is that by copying the src image you copy the whole image to the cropped image.
There are two possibilities:

1 - Without copying data. Its the same as you did. But without the second step. In that case croppedImage is not a real copy it pointed to the data allocated in src.:

```
cv::Mat croppedImage = src(myRoi);
```

2 - With copying the data.

```
cv::Mat croppedImage;
cv::Mat(src, myRoi).copyTo(croppedImage)
```

(one line method - `cv::Mat croppedImage = cv::Mat(src, myRoi).clone();`)

Comment: I had tried your first suggestion before, and when I displayed it, it was very screwed up looking (kind of looked like tv static).  The second method you mention has worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @Jameo your display method probably assumed that the data was continuous which is not true using the first method.

Comment: The second suggestion worked for me while the first one failed.

Comment: @jarora - what kind of error did you get? Please mentoin that in the first case croppedImage and myRoi the image data ptr points to one data object

Comment: thanks! you just saved me. in `Java` (Android) I could use `  `public Mat(Mat m, Rect roi);` - for example - `Mat cropped = new Mat(src, myRoi);` - and it worked good. In iOS I tried first method and didn't work, now I using second method, works fine

Comment: there is also method like `croppedImage = cv::Mat::Mat(src, myRoi);` but seems it also works like first (1) method, and also `cv::Mat(src, myRoi);`

Comment: also one line method (using `clone` instead of `copyTo`) - `cv::Mat croppedImage = cv::Mat(src, myRoi).clone();`

Comment: p.s. also we don't always need to copy it (it better to use first method), until we edit this or trying to convert to `UIImage` (then we have to use second method - copying)