# Match Two Contours of same object in different images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, object-detection

I want to detect an object floating over water. I applied canny edge detector and found all the contours in it. Now I want to match these contours to the contours of another image of the same sight taken with a still camera and very little time gap, to first find the same objects and then calculate how much difference have they covered..
Kindly help me out with this. i searched a lot but couldn't find any thing clear.

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right, you are trying to use the contours of an object to track its position on different images. In this case, you might be interested in [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) techniques.

In short, you'll be using [matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) to find the most probable location of a template (the contour of the object) on another image.

Comment: How can I use template matching in a specific area of the other image??
suppose I only want to match the contour in half of the other image..How can I achieve that?

Comment: @HassanShafiq use a ROI. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041181/equivalent-to-cvsetimageroi-in-the-opencv-c-interface